# Why Generic type can not instantiated?

Tags: java, generics

Here is my question.

```
class Gen<T> {
    T ob;
    Gen() {
        ob = new T(); // Illegal!!!
    }
}
```

Why is it illegal? Could you please explain it.

Comment: @DeadMG Are there languages which would allow some analogous code to compile and still guarantee no runtime errors in case when T happens to be something which cannot be instantiated with no-arg constructor (or at all)?

Comment: @DeadMG You'd have thought so, but I can't find them...

Comment: What should `new Gen<FileInputStream>()` do?

Comment: @scriptin C++ lets you do that

Comment: @scriptin C# has new() constraint which allows to instantiate type parameters with no args constructors https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx

Comment: It is illegal because the runtime doesn't support it.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Though I have never found a place where I'd want to use that constraint over an `Func<T>` factory.

Answer (score 16):

This is impossible because of the following 2 reasons.

1. There is no guarantee that T has a no-args constructor (and for that matter isn't an interface or abstract class)
2. Due to type erasure (required for backwards compatibility) the Type of T is known at compile time but not at run time, so what to construct wouldn't be known.

An answer may be to take a T factory in the constructor. Then Gen can request new Ts to its heart content.

Comment: After compile it will be replaced by Object .                                                     ob = new Object();

Comment: No it won't, you can't cast Object to T. It would break.

Comment: "the Type of T is known at compile time" It is not know at compile time. When compiling this method, the compiler just sees a `T`, and checks to make sure that the code works for all possible `T`. It doesn't know what `T` is.

Comment: @user102008 That cannot be the case. If so `List<String> test=new ArrayList<>(); test.add(new Donkey())` would not be a compile error. Possibly we are meaning two different compile times, the compile time for the `ArrayList` itself and the compile time for the calling context

Comment: @RichardTingle: But that's not in the code for `List` or `ArrayList#add`. That's in the code that uses it. When compiling `ArrayList`, the compiler doesn't know anything about what `T` is.

Comment: @user102008 that's exactly what i was talking about in the second half of my comment. I feel you are deliberately misunderstanding. "At compile time **of the calling context** " T is known. Note "of the calling context", not the ArrayList, which may or may not be compiled at the same time. They are both "at compile time"

Comment: @RichardTingle: But there is only one context at issue in this question -- the generic class `Gen`, and why it doesn't compile. There is no other context relevant to the question. So when you say compile-time, it means at the time of compiling `Gen`.